# ios transitiondelegate with segue

Tags: ios, segue, transition

I have implemented a transitiondelegate, and assigned it to the destination viewcontroller in the segue (at method viewDidLoad). My question is: How iOS knows to use the same delegate when peforming the segue from source to destination? I mean, I didn't assign the delegate at the source viewcontroller. Only assigned it at the destination, and still it is being called when performing the segue.

Who should have the delegate? The presentingViewController or the destinationViewController?

I would expected it to only be called when doing a segue the opposite way.

Thanks, and hope I was clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the transition, the destination view controller asks its transitioning delegate, for the animation controller.
You should set the transitioning delegate for the destination controller.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out yesterday somehow, and this is the correct answer.